# Why do my functions not change the values of my outside variables?

Tags: objective-c, function, xcode4.6

I am using Xcode version 4.6.  In an application for the iPhone and iPad I am making, I made a function called dealCard.  Here it is:

```
- (void)dealCard : (UIImageView *)cardImage : (int)card : (int)suit : (BOOL)aceBool : (int) cardValue : (int)total
{
suit = arc4random() % 4;
card = arc4random() % 13;
if (suit == 0)
{
    //set images

if (suit == 1)
{
   //set images
}

if (suit == 2)
{
    //set images
}

if (suit == 3)
{
    //set images
}
if (card < 10 && card != 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Setting cardValue");
    cardValue = card+1;
}
else if (card != 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Setting cardValue");
    cardValue = 10;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Setting cardValue");
    aceBool = YES;
    if (total + 11 <= 21)
    {
        cardValue = 11;
    }
    else
    {
        cardValue = 1;
    }

}
total = total + cardValue;
NSLog(@"Total = %d cardValue = %d",total,cardValue);
NSLog(@"playerTotal = %d playerCard3Value = %d",playerTotal,playerCard3Value);
}
```

Further down the page I put:

```
[self dealCard: playerCard3Image : playerCard3 : playerSuit3 : playerCard3ace : playerCard3Value : playerTotal];
```

My problem is in the cardValue.  The output says "Setting cardValue", and then the instance variable numbers are both right, but the other two are wrong.  The playerTotal reads whatever the total was before this card was dealt, and the playerCard3Value reads 0.  To give you some context, this function is called not when the first or second card is dealt, but when the third and on are.  The first two are not handled in a function.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Would this be due to the scope of the variables?

Comment: @Matt PsyK - How can I make them global?  I just declare them in the .h file like : `int playerCard3Value;`

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know obj-c or xcode enough to comment.

Comment: you could add instance vars in the containing class, or file vars in the file (effectively class variables) or pass by reference, or - best of all - treat objective-c as an object oriented language: maybe the conjunction of a face value, suit, etc. is a new object called PlayingCard.

Comment: @JohnFarkerson rarely are globals a good idea.  To give a variable scope within the implementation file, they should either be iVars or properties of the class.  Also, that method invocation is a *HORRENDOUS* travesty.  Methods are meant to be self-documenting, not invisible!

Comment: @danh - Making it an object is a great idea!  Thanks!

Comment: @danh - Do you think that will fix the problem?

Comment: i think it will.  cards can be passed around and provide an interface to change their state.  it might even make sense to create a Deck object that can init with 52 cards in an array, and shuffle that array by reordering randomly.  I could code a quick e.g. if you want...

Comment: @danh - If you would be willing to do that, it would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnFarkerson - I did.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object oriented programming is a beautiful thing.  Coded this real fast to show you how it works...

```
//
//  PlayingCard.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PlayingCard : NSObject

- (id)initWithSuit:(NSInteger)suit value:(NSInteger)value;
- (BOOL)isAce;
- (BOOL)isFace;

@end


//
//  PlayingCard.m
//

#import "PlayingCard.h"

@interface PlayingCard ()
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger suit;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger value;

@end

@implementation PlayingCard

- (id)initWithSuit:(NSInteger)suit value:(NSInteger)value {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _suit = suit;
        _value = value;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isAce {
    return self.value == 0;
}

- (BOOL)isFace {
    return self.value > 10;
}

- (NSString *)suitName {
    switch (self.suit) {
        case 0:
            return @"spades";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"diamonds";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"clubs";
            break;
        case 3:
            return @"hearts";
            break;

        default:
            return @"";
            break;
    }
}

// so it prints nicely.  you should consider making the suits enums
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: suit:%@, value:%d", [super description], [self suitName], self.value];
}

@end


//
//  CardDeck.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class PlayingCard;

@interface CardDeck : NSObject

+ (id)cardDeck;
- (void)shuffle;
- (NSUInteger)count;
- (PlayingCard *)dealOne;

@end

//
//  CardDeck.m
//

#import "CardDeck.h"
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@interface CardDeck ()
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *cards;
@end

@implementation CardDeck

+ (id)cardDeck {

    CardDeck *deck = [[self alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
        for (NSInteger value = 0; value < 13; value++) {
            PlayingCard *card = [[PlayingCard alloc] initWithSuit:suit value:value];
            [deck.cards addObject:card];
        }
    }
    return deck;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _cards = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)shuffle {
    NSMutableArray *shuffledCards = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++) {
        int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(52-i);
        [shuffledCards addObject:[self.cards objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
        [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    }
    self.cards = shuffledCards;
}

- (NSUInteger)count {
    return self.cards.count;
}


- (PlayingCard *)dealOne {

    PlayingCard *card = [self.cards lastObject];
    [self.cards removeLastObject];
    return card;
}

@end
```

Call it like this ...

```
CardDeck *deck = [CardDeck cardDeck];
// try it with and without shuffle
[deck shuffle];
while (deck.count) {
    PlayingCard *card = [deck dealOne];
    NSLog(@"%@", card);
}
```